# Dart BLoC with Stream that needs to be updated when either of two Sinks is updated

Tags: dart, flutter, rxdart

I want to have a BLoC class where a Stream output needs to be updated when either/both of two inputs (Sinks) are updated.

How can I wire up the Steam to trigger when either Sink is updated / distinct?

```
import 'package:escapemodels/src/bloc/blocbase.dart';
import 'package:rxdart/rxdart.dart';

class MathAddBloc implements BlocBase {
  final Sink<int> x;
  final Sink<int> y;
  final Stream<int> addxy;

  factory MathAddBloc() {

    final x = PublishSubject<int>();
    final y = PublishSubject<int>();

  // This is the part that I am confused about - I can figure how to trigger when one Sink/Observable changes but not when either one is updated.
    final addxy = x
    .distinct()
    .switchMap<int>((int x) => (x + y.last))
    .startWith(0);

    return MathAddBloc._(x,y, addxy);
  }


  MathAddBloc._(this.x, this.y, this.addxy);

  void dispose() {
    x.close();
    y.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [combineLatest2](https://pub.dev/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/Rx/combineLatest2.html) method.

You might want to have a look at [this video](https://youtu.be/7O1UO5rEpRc) too, which I found really useful when doing something similar.